# Prove that there is an $x_0\in(0,1]$ s.t. $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $0\leq x<x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)=0$. Prove that there is a number $x_0\in(0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $0\leq x<x_0$.

Intuitively, if I think about this function on a graph, we can take a negative cubic function that has a y-intercept greater than 0 and an x-intercept equal to 1 with a local minimum on the x-axis between 0 and 1. However, I am not sure how to prove this for some general function $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $x_0=\inf \{x: f(x)=0\}$. Use continuity to show that $f(x_0)=0$. It is obvious by definition that $f(x) >0$ for $x <x_0$. [Certainly $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x<x_0$. If $0<x<x_0$ and $f(x) <0$ then by IVP there must be some point $y \in (0,x)$ such that $f(y)=0$ but that would contradict the definition of $x_0$].

Comment: Can you explain more on how to use continuity to show that $f(x_0)=0$? Would I have to define a sequence and show that it converges to 0?

Comment: By definition of infimum there exists  sequence $(x_n)$ in $\{x: f(x)=0\}$ which converges to $x_0$. So $f(x_0)=\lim f(x_n)=lim 0=0$. [This also shows that $x_0$ cannot be $0$ so we have $0 <x_0 \leq 1]$. @JamesAnderson

Comment: @JamesAnderson I have also added some steps for showing that $f(x) >0$ for $x <x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f^{-1}(0)$ is a closed subset of the compact set $[0,1]$ it is compact, let $x_0$ be its minimum.